# C# MD5CryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, encryption, md5

I am currently converting a legacy ASP.NET 1.1 application into a .NET 4 MVC 3 application.

I am looking at the password encryption and a routine was written in the old code to use the MD5CryptoServiceProvider.

```
        private string EncryptText(string szText)
        {
            try
            {
                UTF8Encoding objEncoder = new UTF8Encoding();                
                MD5CryptoServiceProvider objMD5Hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                Byte[] btHashedDataBytes = objMD5Hasher.ComputeHash(objEncoder.GetBytes(szText));
                string szReturn = objEncoder.GetString(btHashedDataBytes);
                objEncoder = null;
                objMD5Hasher = null;

                return szReturn;
            }
            catch
            {               
                return "";
            }
        }
```

I have written a quick .NET 4 console application and copied this function so I can do a comparison against the current passwords in the database (to make sure the MD5 function still gives me the same output)

```
            string encTxt = encryptor.EncryptText("fbloggsPass12345");

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=server;Database=db;User Id=sa;Password=1111;"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;                   

                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE SiteUsers SET Token = '" + encTxt + "' WHERE PKey = 10";
                    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                        Console.WriteLine("Updated");
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Failed");

                }
                conn.Close();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

However the password in the database is currently !?MGF+&> and the output I am getting is ���!?��MGF�+&��> which when I store in the database converts to ???!???MGF?+&??>

Which I can see is almost the same, but why am I getting the ? characters

Answer (score 5):

This is the first problem, at least:

```
string szReturn = objEncoder.GetString(btHashedDataBytes);
```

You're trying to use the hash as if it were UTF-8-encoded text. It's not - it's just arbitrary binary data.

If you need to convert arbitrary binary data to text, you should use something like Base64 (e.g. `Convert.ToBase64String`) or hex.

(Additionally, I would *strongly* advise you not to "handle" exceptions in the way you're doing so at the moment. Why would you want to hide problems like that? And why are you setting variables to `null` just before they go out of scope anyway?)

Oh, and *please* don't include values directly in your SQL like that - use parameterized SQL instead.

Finally, I would use a different hashing algorithm these days, particularly for passwords. Can you not use an off-the-shelf system for authentication, which is actually developed by security experts? Security is difficult: we'd all be better off leaving it to the relatively few people who know how to do it right :) See comments for more suggestions.

Comment: As I said this was a quick console application to test the function and isn't production code. The EncryptText function was copied from an application written years ago and the error handling will be completely revised.

Comment: @AndrewRayner: That doesn't make the code any better :) The fundamental problem is the encoding part, but it's worth paying attention to all the other problems too.

Comment: I agree the code is crap :) I am just trying to prove a concept before we put this into the new project. I will try your suggestion regarding the issue :) thanks!

Comment: @AndrewRayner: Note that my suggestion won't help with the *existing* data in the database. That's basically garbage, if it was created with the original code. Using Base64 you should be able to store and update *new* data though.

Comment: But if we do that won't we need to ask all the users to change their password? As it will need to be encrypted again?

Comment: @AndrewRayner: Yes, it will need to be hashed again. (Not really encrypted; this is one-way.) You should take that as a given - your original code was simply broken. I would do a global password reset - and take this opportunity to move off MD-5 at the same time. See the bottom paragraph of my (edited) answer.

Comment: Choice of hash function is mostly irrelevant in this context. Even for MD5 the strongest attack is guessing the password. Using a unique per-user salt and a strengthening scheme such as PBKDF2 (make it slow) are *far* more important. PBKDF1-SHA1 is implemented in the [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx). **Single iteration SHA-256 even with a salt is not acceptable.**

Comment: Sounds like the best way going forward.. We do have an Encryption class that we use for most of our application which uses SHA-256 and a salt. We were trying to reduce impact to the users.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: This is why I suggested at least looking into it further, and ideally using a better off-the-shelf solution :) I've edited to remove the SHA-256 + salt suggestion, as it would be inadequate.

Answer (score 1):

The standard technique for low impact upgrading is using the old hash as input for the new hashing scheme. This works pretty well with normal MD5 hashes.

Unfortunately for you, you were sending the binary hash through a non binary safe encoding (UTF8). This replaced every second character by 0xFFFD, effectively halving the output size to 64 bits. This weakens an upgraded scheme considerably but not fatally.

I'd upgrade the existing hashes to `PBKDF2(legacyHash, salt)`, then on user login replace the hash with a new hash `PBKDF2(password, salt)` that doesn't depend on the legacy scheme. After a few months trigger a password reset for all users who did not login yet, getting rid of the legacy hash based passwords.

For the new scheme, I'd go with PBKDF2-SHA-1 which is implemented in the  [Rfc2898DeriveBytes Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx). Use sufficient iterations, at least 10000.